# What cause the error opening trace file: No such file or directory?

Tags: java, android, xml

When I run my app in my mobile device, I get this under the logcat :

**error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)** . Any one know what met be the cause? I tried to re-build the project and clean it under:

Project >  Clean...

But I still get the same error. The app says unfortunately the you cant record on this device, of which is a message I have created under my String.xml files if the phone does not support recordings.

Any one with help please do so. I will be happy to get one.

Here is the code:
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public static final String FILE_DIRECTORY = "iRecorded_Calls";
public ListView listView;
public ScrollView mScrollView;
public TextView mTextView;
public static final String LISTEN_ENABLED = "ListenEnabled";
private static final int CATEGORY_DETAIL = 1;
private static final int NO_MEMORY_CARD = 2;
private static final int TERMS = 3;

public RadioButton radEnable;
public RadioButton radDisable;

public static final int MEDIA_MOUNTED = 0;
public static final int MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY = 1;
public static final int NO_MEDIA = 2;

private static Resources res;
private Context context;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));

    res = getResources();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);        
    mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView02);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNoRecords);

    SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences(LISTEN_ENABLED,
            0);
    boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);

    if (!silent)
        showDialog(CATEGORY_DETAIL);

    context = this.getBaseContext();

}
//Explorer the file directory 
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (updateExternalStorageState() == MEDIA_MOUNTED) {
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath();
        final File file = new File(filepath, FILE_DIRECTORY);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        final List<Model> listDir = ListDir2(file);

        filepath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        final File file2 = new File(filepath, FILE_DIRECTORY);

        if (!file2.exists()) {
            file2.mkdirs();
        }

        final List<Model> listDir2 = ListDir2(file2);

        listDir.addAll(listDir2);

        if (listDir.isEmpty()) {
            mScrollView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
            listView.setVisibility(ScrollView.GONE);
        } else {
            mScrollView.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
            listView.setVisibility(ScrollView.VISIBLE);
        }

        final CallsAdapter adapter = new CallsAdapter(this, listDir);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                adapter.showPromotionPieceDialog(listDir.get(position)
                        .getCallName(), position);
            }
        });
```

Comment: How about posting the code that builds the filename/path and writes to the file.

Comment: @GaryBak - the code that does that is a (buggy) part of the system, not the poster's project.  The actual message is ignorable - at most it is being triggered *after* the poster's code crashes for some other reason (that would be worth investigating) but it can also occur because something else on the device happens to crash at a time close to when the poster is testing their project.

Comment: The traces file thing is spurious, you need to find error messages actually related to your code.  If you are trying to record calls, be aware that is not necessarily supported.

Comment: @Chiris Stratton, I have the following under my manifest `android:minSdkVersion="15"` and target to be `android:targetSdkVersion="21"`

I want my app to work from Android 4.0 upwards, by upwards meaning for android for till android 5.0.

I'm also trying to figure what is that I did wrong in some other part of my code, cause at some point it does crush. Giving me the message that says **call recorder cant record this call**. It does that for incoming call and outgoing one, so I will have to dig hard on what II did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figured out what was the problem on my code and fixed it and now I can be able to recorder the incoming and outgoing calls. The problem was under my *RecordSercive* class on the recorder part

```
> //________Test with the Default outputFormat and default
> Encoder________
> 
>           /*  recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
>               recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
>               recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);*/
>               
>               //_______End for the Test with the Default outputFortmat and default Encoder________
```

That is where I got the Message that says  *unfortunately the you cant record on this device*

So I changed my code to this:

```
> recorder = new MediaRecorder();               
>               recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK + MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK);//test using the addition sign
> for both DOWNLINK + UPLINK
>               recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
>               recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);                
>               myFileName = getFilename();
>               recorder.setOutputFile(myFileName);
```

Which worked fine for me, but the sound quality is is a problem, of which I will just have to increase the volume using the

```
> volume = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

but under the LogCat the on Eclipse when I debug my app, I still get the **error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)**. Of which I think it might be caused by other reasons of which I'm currently investigating like (Chris Stratton) mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

In the latest version of Android they have clearly restricted working with a network of the main stream.
This had been done for UI not to break.
Possibly you raised the API version in the manifest.

Comment: Unless you can point to any evidence that the poster is performing network operations, this is wild speculation which would at most barely rise to the level of a comment.